# IOS iPad build fails at touch (before code signing)

Tags: ios, build

I recently finished the iPhone build of this software and it is successfully up for review.  The iPad version is markedly different in UI so I am now attempting to get it on the App Store.  However, the build is failing after "Touch" and won't code sign.  I am using the same certificates I used for the iPhone version.  Do I need new ones?

Thanks for your time.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  I was using a '~' in the identifiers and touch choked on it.  Removed the tilde and all is well and its waiting for review on the app store.